# How to automate the scraping of AJAX headers?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping some data using AJAX via `.post` method, think financial instrument quotes.

However, the get the headers for the request for each instrument I have to manually submit the form in a browser and then open the dev view in order to manually write the form headers (data ID).

Is there a way to automate this process? I.e. to have a script that crawls through a website and gets all available headers, for example by trying and submitting all available forms?

Each instrument's ID is in a form of a series of numbers, e.g. 28571, so I thought about trying all integers from 0 to 1000000 or something like that, but the problem is that the response only contains the numerical data, without a label.

Comment: By "headers," you mean the names of the form elements?  You could use a HTML parser and pull out the `<form>` tags and get all its `<input>`, etc. elements and then you should have the data you need to post.

Comment: Sorry if it came out unclear. By headers I mean the 'payload' as in here: page = requests.post(url, data=payload), that is what I post via the form.